# Kernel panic when booting from USB stick to install 7

Tags: system-installation, kernel, install, live-installation, eos7

I'm trying to upgrade my laptop to OS 7 but I'm running into a kernel panic. This while I can boot into Ubuntu 22.04 created in the same way, booting from the same USB stick.

I'm on a Dell XPS 15 9550 (with NVIDIA GTX 960M). I'm using the same USB stick, USB port and Balena Etcher install.
I've used balenaEtcher-1.14.3-x64.AppImage
For both I went into bios to put usb drive as first option in the boot sequence.

I've Downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.1 (ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)
Selected: Try or install Ubuntu (first option)
Boots just fine into welcome install screen.

Downloaded elementary OS (elementaryos-7.0-stable.20230129rc.iso)
(using magnet link)
I've verified the checksum following: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download
When booting I select the Try or install elementary OS option.

I get this error momentarily:

```
error: Out of memory.
Press any key to continue...
```

And then the following kernel panic:

```
[ 0.229634] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS,
[ 0.599320] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H
EC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.599338] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.599588] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H
EC.ECAV], RE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.599603] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.599705] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H
EC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.599718] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.599812] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H
EC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.599824] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[ 0.697892] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[ 0.697968] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu
[ 0.698035] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9550/0N7TVV, BIOS 1.14.0 02/13/2020
[ 0.698099]  Call Trace:
[ 0.698122]  <TASK>
[ 0.698143]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
[ 0.698181]  dump_stack_1v1+0x4a/0x63
[ 0.698217]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
[ 0.698248]  panic+0x149/0x321
[ 0.698279]  mount_block_root+0x144/0x1dd
[ 0.698318]  mount_root+0x10c/0x11c
[ 0.698351]  prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x191
[ 0.698388]  kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x1b5
[ 0.698430]  ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
[ 0.698464]  kernel_init+0x1b/0x150
[ 0.698497]  ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
[ 0.698535]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
[ 0.698571]  </TASK>
[ 0.698641] Kernel Offset: 0x6800000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[ 0.698754] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

I've tried reflashing and booting again.
I've also tried the Save graphics option.
Both fail.

Ubuntu 22.04 is what elementary OS 7 is based on, I don't understand what could be going wrong here.

Comment: I have the same machine, but am trying to boot into Zorin. I followed the instructions and got passed the error: Out of memory But now I'm seeing the following[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB92a.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB92a.jpg) Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried defining a resolution in the gfxmode, like: https://github.com/elementary/os/pull/609/files#diff-f992683b78497b4a7b42a69b871cc2bb3d7db661ba6732e15f8f2e89e06abe43R3 ?

Comment: Yes, tried that and even tried disconnecting the laptop monitor and booting from an external monitor and still get the black screen after the initial grub selection, not sure why  or how to overcome this issue. FYI, I'm trying to boot into Zorin 16.2 which is based on Ubuntu 20.04, so I'm thinking it's something to do with the kernel that's not allowing it to get past the initial boot menu. Any other ideas?

Comment: Zorin OS is not Elementary OS ... 

Answer (score 1):

I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/542), which resulted in [this PR](https://github.com/elementary/os/pull/609). Building the ISO based on that PR following [these instructions](https://github.com/elementary/os#64-bit-amdintel), flashing that to an USB stick and then booting from it seems to work!